# GPE for Eclipse Indigo Installation Error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation, gwt2

I'm trying to use Eclipse **Indigo** with Google Plugin for Eclipse (GPE), but can't found GPE 3.7. I mean, that i'll be satisfied with GPE 3.6.

Now i have this error with GPE3.6 installation:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.6 2.2.0.v201102111811 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e36.feature.feature.group 2.2.0.v201102111811)
  Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.6 2.2.0.v201102111811 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e36.feature.feature.group 2.2.0.v201102111811) requires '**org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.0,3.7.0)**' but it could not be found

What is org.eclipse.platform.feature.group? What kind of package i must to install?

Answer (score 12):

Just use http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7 as a plugin repository

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same error, but for the Oracle ADF plugin. Looks like we have to upgrade to Helios (3.6).

Comment: Yes, but Helios didn't support Java7 yet.. I think, we should expect to release the official version of GPE for Indigo from Google.

Comment: You might consider removing this, as it's not related to this question which is about the GPE. The error is generic and indicates you are trying to install something on a version of Eclipse that does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not ready yet:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/15fd62a17c3e6fd5?pli=1

Answer (score -1):

Indigo is 4.1, the plug-ins from Google will need to be re-worked or Eclipse will need to include the [3.6,3.7] package. The later of which, I do not see happening.

Comment: No, Indigo is 3.7 and the plugin can be installed on [3.6,3.7) which is not inclusive of 3.7